# How can my find/du be faster?

Tags: bash, directory, find, solaris, du

How can a find can be faster in some huge directories ?

Example, I start this command : find . -group toto -prune exec du -sh {} \;

But it stays blocked on some huge directories and never (or perhaps if I wait the all day) give me an answer.

My system : Solaris 10.

Thanks

Comment: if you are looking for just files, do `find | grep 'file1'` . If you are looking for something specific, then find a command that can dump all that specific information into a file and `grep` search through it. grep is amazingly fast, and if you have a file that stores info that you need, you will be happy.

Comment: The goal of this find is to calculate the size of the directories with "du" command. Unfortunately to do this I can't forward the result of a find or a ls -ltR in a file.

Comment: if it's blocked on certain huge directories, check with `ls` or globbing; it could be the filesystem used that just doesn't like large directories

Answer (score 1):

I think your runtime is quadratic, because `du` already *sums* the files inside the trees you named.

The following will make the traversal much faster because it spawns no processes outside find:

```
find . -group toto -prune -o -printf '%s\t%p\n'
```

This will list e.g.

```
68  ./.profiles/sehe/.cache/upstart/im-config.log.1.gz
68  ./.profiles/sehe/.cache/upstart/im-config.log.2.gz
71  ./.profiles/sehe/.cache/upstart/im-config.log.3.gz
```

Note you can report 512 blocks (`%b`), which reports the actually allocated size (even if the file is sparse).

Using my crystal ball, it looks like you might want to report on usage by group or by user:

```
 find . -group toto -prune -o -printf '%g\t%b\n' | sort -k2n -k1,1
```

Which prints e.g.

```
group1  2200
group1  2208
group1  2216
group1  2480
group1  2648
group1  2784
group1  3656
group1  3664
group1  3768
group1  4360
group1  5112
group1  5952
group1  6416
group1  7248
group2  8192
group2  8192
group2  8192
group2  9696
group2  12760
group2  19944
group2  33264
group2  34936
```

It should be relatively easy to postprocess this information to get the results you are really after, for example with `q` (see github):

```
sehe@desktop:/tmp$ sudo find . -printf '%g %b\n' | ./q "select c1,sum(2) from - group by c1"
gdm 10
root 22
someone 18
sehe 2826
```

Answer (score 0):

if the . directory is a mount point try:

```
df -h .
```

If the current directory is not a mount point, ask du to look just at directory files and report in kbytes, du -h gives differing units (K, MB, etc.)  so you cannot add them, du -ks prints consistent units:

```
find . -type d -group toto -prune -exec du -ks {} \; |
awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum, " Blocks"}'
```